# How do I combine two Union Types to make a third Type, similar to string interpolation, in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have two types:

`type FiatType = 'USD' | 'GBP' | 'EUR' ...`

`type CryptoType = 'BTC' | 'BCH' | 'ETH' ...`

I want to create a PairType

`type PairType = 'USD-BTC' | 'USD-BCH' | 'USD-ETH' | 'GBP-BTC' | 'GBP-BCH' ...`

Is something like that possible in TypeScript?

Comment: I'm almost confident that it is not possible in TypeScript. Though, will be glad to see the trick on achieving this (if possible) too

Comment: I'd model this as a tuple. Maybe it's possible to "multiply" both sets but it seems like an overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not yet supported in Typescript. There are some issues opened (like [this one](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12754)) but they are not on the roadmap yet as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a bit too late, but I just tried to dig the same problem and found something in the documentation of TypeScript. I suppose this feature has been added since version 4.1.5.

There is an example how it works:

```js
type FiatType = 'USD' | 'GBP' | 'EUR';
type CryptoType = 'BTC' | 'BCH' | 'ETH';
 
type PairType = `${FiatType}-${CryptoType }`;
```

More info you can find here - https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html

And also pull request with decription - https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40336